# PHP Array Random Variable not switching out on page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin on a WordPress site. I have a repeater field with 25+ quotes that I am displaying on a per page basis. Each page has unique quotes.

The code I currently have to pull one random quote from that pool of 25 works just as it is suppose to when I am logged in. When I log out, it does pull one random quote but will not switch it out to a different one on page refresh like it does when I am logged in.

I am using this random row code from here:
https://gist.github.com/wesrice/1924934

```
<?php       
        if (is_singular('post')) {
            $repeater2 = get_field( 'quote_info', 11 ); 
            $random_rows2 = array_rand( $repeater2, 1 );        
                if( is_array( $random_rows2 ) ){
                    foreach( $random_rows2 as $random_row2 ){       
                        echo '<div class="newquote">                            
                                <div class="newinnerwrapperquote">&quot;' . $repeater2[$random_row2]['bottom_quote_text'] . '&quot;</div>';
                        echo '<div class="newquoteby">' . $repeater2[$random_row2]['bottom_quote_author'] . '</div></div>';
                    }
                } else {                

                    echo '<div class="newquote">                            
                                <div class="newinnerwrapperquote">&quot;' . $repeater2[$random_rows2]['bottom_quote_text'] . '&quot;</div>';
                    echo '<div class="newquoteby">' . $repeater2[$random_rows2]['bottom_quote_author'] . '</div></div>';
                }   wp_reset_query();
        } else {
            $repeater = get_field( 'quote_info' );          
            $random_rows = array_rand( $repeater, 1 );  
            if( is_array( $random_rows ) ){
                foreach( $random_rows as $random_row ){     
                    echo '<div class="newquote">                            
                            <div class="newinnerwrapperquote">&quot;' . $repeater[$random_row]['bottom_quote_text'] . '&quot;</div>';
                    echo '<div class="newquoteby">' . $repeater[$random_row]['bottom_quote_author'] . '</div></div>';
                }
            } else {                

                echo '<div class="newquote">                            
                            <div class="newinnerwrapperquote">&quot;' . $repeater[$random_rows]['bottom_quote_text'] . '&quot;</div>';
                echo '<div class="newquoteby">' . $repeater[$random_rows]['bottom_quote_author'] . '</div></div>';
            }   

        }

?>
```

The first if statement is if it is on a WordPress post rather than a page. I hope I explained this well.

Comment: random guess .. caching

Answer (score 0):

Internal caching plugin was activated. Turned it off and works now when not logged in.